# Updating android notification

Tags: android, notifications

I have an app that downloads files. I've created a notification when a file is downloaded. When multiple files are downloaded I want to update this notification with the list of files that were updated. I know I do that by using a notification id. My problem is how do I know if the notification was cleared? 
For instance let say it is downloading 4 files a,b,c,d . After it finishes downloading file a I create a notification that says

```
1 file donwloaded  
file A
```

Then when it downloads B I update it to say

```
2 files donwloaded  
file A and file B
```

I can do that by caching the files that have been downloaded. My problem is if at this point the user clears the notification. If he does that, when file C finishes downloading I would want to update the message to say

```
1 file donwloaded  
file C
```

rather than

```
3 files donwloaded  
file A, file B and file B
```

For that I need to clear my cache or use another mechanism, does anyone know how to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [deleteIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#deleteIntent) to specify a PendingIntent to be executed when the user clears your notification.

> The intent to execute when the notification is explicitly dismissed by
>   the user, either with the "Clear All" button or by swiping it away
>   individually. 
>       This probably shouldn't be launching an activity since several of those will be sent at the same time.